# Sitecore Multilingual - Parsing item to InternalLinkField converts its language

Tags: sitecore, multilingual

I'm working on a multilingual module right now and having problems with parsing a field to `InternalLinkField`. What happens is that I have an item in Chinese language, but when I get one of its field and convert it to `InternalLinkField` the converted item becomes English. Here's the sample code:

```
var field = (InternalLinkField)InnerItem.Fields["Test"];
```

So, the current item that I'm working on is the `InnerItem`, it is in Chinese version and when parsed the field object becomes English. So, as a workaround for now I used the context item to get the field with the language.

My workaround:

```
Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(field.TargetID, InnerItem.Language);
```

But, it is redundant and I want to know the right way to get the field object with the correct language version.

Answer (score 1):

*InternalLinkField* is a system type used by Sitecore core. Hence, it is not recommended to use it for your custom features development unless you plan to extend Sitecore considerably. If you want to implement a link field in your data template then the following two types will be suitable for your need:

- *LinkField* if you want to cover both internal and external links, i.e. admins can either select a Sitecore item or specify an external URL; you can simply use `GetFriendlyUrl()` method to generate the correct link as

`Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField yourLinkField = yourItem.Fields["Link"];`

`var yourUrl = yourLinkField.GetFriendlyUrl();`

- *Droplink* if you want to restrict only to selection of a Sitecore item, such field will store ID of the selected item as value.